# Analysis of longitudinal data where final visit was earlier for subset of patients

Tags: panel-data

I have a longitudinal dataset with visits 1, 2, 3 and 4, several weeks apart. The outcome is binary, and the aim is to assess the covariates associated with the presence/absence of this variable at visit 4.

Most patients adhered to the protocol and attended the final visit (visit 4) in the visit window given, however due to COVID, a subset of patients were called in earlier, and attended their final visit outside of the visit window (between visit 3 and 4). Had these patients waited and attended as stipulated in the protocol, those that were absent when they attended their final visit may have been observed as present.

Would it possible to use mixed effects logistic regression models with an additional visit between 3 and 4 in the outcome (5 visits in total), to address those that attended their final visit earlier. Would this violate the missing at random assumption for mixed effects models?

Alternatively, would a logistic regression model suffice where the outcome is the binary variable at visit 4, adjusting for the time to the final visit as a covariate in the model?

Are there any methods that can handle scenarios like this, which are common with real-world data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subjects attend visits out of window all the time, and, as a statistician, you know there is nothing intrinsically useful about the window itself, it's just a matter of finding balance in design to reduce influence of exogenous factors, and, more importantly, a measure of compliance. Even precautionary "COVID" deviations are potentially an informative missingness mechanism. I've heard of cardiovascular trials including COVID19 infection as a composite with primary endpoints as a sensitivity analysis...

I would suggest that, for an intent to treat analysis, you analyze the endpoints as-is. I assume there was no planned adjustment for time using a fixed effect. I would further suggest that for a sensitivity analysis, you fit the main effect model without the OOW patients as a per-protocol population. You may additionally consider the same mixed effects model with a variety of variance structures, in particular inclusion of a random slope in time as a nested effect within subject.